# Subscriber on Mosquitto MQTT ContentType is Null

Tags: c#, mqtt, mosquitto, mqttnet

I'm trying to publish a serialized message and sending the ContentType of that object type, so when I receive the message on the subscriber I know which type I can deserialize back to.

Here is the publish code:

```
public async Task PublishByTopicAsync<T>(string topic, T payload)
    {
        var payloadInBytes = _serializer.SerializeObject(payload);
        var message = new MqttApplicationMessage()
        {
            Topic = topic,
            PayloadFormatIndicator = MqttPayloadFormatIndicator.CharacterData,
            ContentType = "json",//payload?.GetType().FullName,
            Payload = payloadInBytes,
            QualityOfServiceLevel = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtMostOnce
        };
        await _mqttClient.Value.Result.EnqueueAsync(message);
    }
```

On the receiving side I get this:

[image]

Any idea how can I send the type of object on publishing, and receive it on the subscriber?

Comment: What MQTT version are you connecting to the broker with? Only messages sent via MQTT v5 will have a PayloadFormatIndicator

Comment: I am using MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient" Version="4.0.2.221. How do I know which MQTT protocol is used?

Comment: Ok I've added ".WithProtocolVersion(MqttProtocolVersion.V500)" on the WithClientOptions and it now works :) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comments, `PayloadFormatIndicator` is only available when both clients are connected to the broker with MQTT v5